# perl style regex - get the nth(4th) word in a piped sentence - a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|n|o

Tags: regex, styles, pcre

I am very new in perl style **regex**. Can somebody suggest me the get the **nth word** in a piped sentence.

Sentence:

`ab|gf|fdg|hjtyt|ew|gf|jh|edf|gfd|fd|fd|jvf|df|ds|s|gf`

I wanted to get here **4th word**: `hjtyt`

I am using a tool where I can only put the perl style regex, so I am looking for a regex solution only.

Comment: Do you really mean Perl *style* regex (i. e. PCRE), or actually the language Perl?

Comment: Which tool are you using? What do you want to do with the matched text?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a regex for this. In Python:

```
>>> s = "ab|gf|fdg|hjtyt|ew|gf|jh|edf|gfd|fd|fd|jvf|df|ds|s|gf"
>>> s.split("|")[3]
'hjtyt'
```

But if you insist:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"^(?:[^|]*\|){3}([^|]*)", s).group(1)
'hjtyt'
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
(?:     # Match...
 [^|]*  # Any number of characters except pipes,
 \|     # followed by a pipe,
){3}    # repeated three times.
(       # Match and capture into group number 1:
 [^|]*  # Any number of characters except pipes.
)       # End of capturing group number 1
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I am using a tool where I can only put the perl style regex, so I am looking for a regex solution only. Thanks

Comment: That would be the raw string used as the pattern in the above explanation: `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}([^|]*)`

Comment: Though technically you can take out two of the parentheses: `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*`

Comment: @KyleStrand: But then your search result would include the entire string up to the fourth "word" without any way to isolate that word.

Comment: Oh, right, I was thinking of a lookbehind, I guess. Which wouldn't actually work in this context anyway, since it's not fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

use [*autosplit*](http://perldoc.perl.org/AutoSplit.html) in perl:

```
> echo "ab|gf|fdg|hjtyt|ew|gf|jh" | perl -F"\|" -lane 'print $F[3]'
hjtyt
>
```